# How to set CreateParams after the constructor has run?

Tags: delphi, window, delphi-xe2, vcl

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    FAppWindow: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    property AppWindow: Boolean read FAppWindow write FAppWindow;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.AppWindow := True;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  if FAppWindow then begin
    Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    Params.WndParent := 0;
  end;
end;
```

This doesn't work, because the window handle is created during the constructor of TForm, so `CreateParams` is run too early and `FAppWindow` is always `False`.

Writing a custom constructor also doesn't work since you have to eventually call the inherited constructor which creates the handle before you can save any data to the instance:

```
constructor TForm2.CreateAppWindow(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FAppWindow := True;
end;
```

Is there a way to:

- Delay the creation of the window handle?
- Alter the window style after creation of the window handle?
- Recreate the window handle after the constructor has run?
- Some other option I haven't thought of, yet?

How can I change the style of a form from the "outside" of the class?

Comment: Write a setter for that property that will `RecreateWnd`.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to re-create the window, you could do what the `ChangeAppWindow` internal procedure does. It sets the style by `SetWindowLong` inside a pair of `ShowWindow` calls (`SW_HIDE` and `SW_SHOW` or `SW_MINIMIZE` pair). I would prefer re-creation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to pass the parameter to the form in its constructor, rather than wait until it has finished being created.

That means you need to introduce a constructor for `TForm2` that accepts as parameters whatever information you need to pass on in `CreateParams`.

Make a note of any state before you call the inherited constructor. Also, there's no need to set `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` when you are setting the owner to be zero.

Comment: Make a note of the param before calling inherited. This is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, this is how `CreateParented` does

Comment: I had an access violation when I tried something like this, but now it seems to work, curious. Is it possible that `Self` is not initialized in the constructor under certain circumstances?

Comment: 1) You call the constructor without assigning. `TMyClass.Create();`instead of `c := TMyClass.Create();`  2) You call the constructor using the variable instead of the class. `c.Create();` 3) You are using variables of `Self` which not yet has been initialized.

Comment: You can read and write from fields, but they'll be default initialized.

Answer (score 4):

The nice thing about Delphi is that a derived constructor DOES NOT have to call the `inherited` constructor as its *first* statement.  So you can set your `FAppWindow` member first, THEN call the `inherited` constructor to stream the DFM and create the window, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.CreateAppWindow(Self);
  Form2.Show;
end;

constructor TForm2.CreateAppWindow(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FAppWindow := True;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work to recreate the handle, I got the idea from the `RecreateAsPopup` VCL method:

```
procedure TForm2.SetAppWindow(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FAppWindow := Value;
  if HandleAllocated then
    RecreateWnd
  else
    UpdateControlState;
end;
```